# Create email account from Shell

Tags: email, shell

Here's the thing:

- I have shell/ssh access to the remote host
- I don't have cPanel or something like that
- Domain is, lets say, mydomain.com
- What I want is to create new email account, something like bounced@mydomain.com. That needs to be done via shell, as I don't have cPanel there.

I searched and searched and found tons of cPanel solutions, but non that covers shell.

Just to be clear: question is not how to send/receive emails, but to create new email account with username and password.

Any suggestion will be highly appreciated! :)

Comment: what OS? You might be able to succesfully ask this at one of the unix QA sites if unix. You will need to provide more information about what pop/smtp/exchange/whatever email server you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well that really depends on the mail server, doesn't it?

From a quick google search, I found this for sendmail:
http://mohammednv.wordpress.com/2008/01/07/how-to-create-a-new-mail-account-in-sendmail/

You need to edit a file and call a program (useradd). I guess both as root.

You will have to find out what email server you are running and how to configure it/add users. Doing this from shell (or remote shell, doesn't matter) really is the normal way of doing this. So this isn't at all a question about programming. You might want to look at superuser or serverfault stack exchange sites.